# Freeze on a white page on run android-device for meteor based mobile application

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, cordova, meteor

I tried to write a mobile application for my web application. I have two application that both of them written with meteor.js. I run my web application simply with `meteor` command (run on http://localhost:3000) and then run my mobile application with this command:

> export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor
>
> meteor run android-device --port 5000 --verbose

It's successfully run on port 5000 and I can run that from my browser but It's not working on mobile device.

On mobile I show a white page in mobile screen and this result on terminal as log:

> => Started app on Android Device.              I20160225-16:16:49.717(3.5)
>   (android:file:///android_asset/www/meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR
>   CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url:
>   http://meteor.local I20160225-16:16:53.683(3.5) (android:0)
>   'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM
>   (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach).
>   I20160225-16:16:54.378(3.5)
>   (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:338) METEOR
>   CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) cordova.file.dataDirectory is
>   null, retrying in 20ms I20160225-16:16:55.008(3.5)
>   (android:http://meteor.local/packages/meteor.js:906) Exception from
>   Tracker recompute function: I20160225-16:16:55.010(3.5)?
>   I/chromium(14653): [INFO:CONSOLE(906)] "TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function I20160225-16:16:55.011(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   RouteController.extend.data
>   (http://meteor.local/app/client/views/index/indexController.js?817b64fb75670270418a553ed48a884bd8841492:17:32)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.012(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at null._data
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/iron_controller.js?20327f0adf618028f4e33ee2fc6d6af85b26fc9f:220:50)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.013(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   DynamicTemplate.data
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?ebc5266f87a0be7618b1f690df32f1aa90ec89d7:213:50)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.013(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   http://meteor.local/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?ebc5266f87a0be7618b1f690df32f1aa90ec89d7:246:25
>   I20160225-16:16:55.014(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   null.
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:2613:26)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.015(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1872:20
>   I20160225-16:16:55.015(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3671:12)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.016(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1870:29
>   I20160225-16:16:55.017(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at
>   Object.Blaze._withCurrentView
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:2211:12)
>   I20160225-16:16:55.018(3.5)? I/chromium(14653):     at viewAutorun
>   (http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1869:18)",
>   source:
>   http://meteor.local/packages/meteor.js?9418708e9519b747d9d631d85ea85b90c0b5c70c
>   (906) I20160225-16:17:21.394(3.5)? I/chromium(15182):
>   [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level =
>   0, default verbosity = 0 I20160225-16:17:21.521(3.5)?
>   W/chromium(15182): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)]
>   locale_file_path.empty() I20160225-16:17:21.523(3.5)?
>   I/chromium(15182): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk
>   succesful, fd=33 off=43796 len=3029 I20160225-16:17:21.524(3.5)?
>   I/chromium(15182): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading
>   webviewchromium.pak from, fd:34 off:230172 len:1089587

I think in above message the key note is that refer to one of my files:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function: "TypeError: undefined is
>   not a function
>   http://meteor.local/app/client/views/index/indexController.js?817b64fb75670270418a553ed48a884bd8841492:17:32)

And this is my ***indexController.js***:

```
IndexController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'index',

    waitOn: function () {
        return [Meteor.subscribe('allRootCategories'), Meteor.subscribe('allRootArticles')];
    },

    data: function () {

        return {
            categories: Categories.find({}),
            articles: Articles.find({})
        }
    },

    action: function () {
        this.render();
    }
});
```

I also tried to add a ***mobile-config.js*** file with below content but nothing change:

`App.accessRule('*');`

What is the problem?

---

***Update:***

As @Phonolog say in comments I debug application with [chrome inspect tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) and I see that line 17 is my query line below:

```
categories: Categories.find({}),
```

Comment: Maybe you could mark line 17 in your code, as the error seems to occur there. Anyway the undefined is not a function-error often happens when you try to call a method on undefined object.

Comment: @Phonolog Line 17 is this ( this.render(); ). It's work correctly on browser without any issue but has error on mobile. I don't know which object being undefined.

Comment: You could try using [chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) to debug this line on your device and see if this is defined...

Comment: @Phonolog I debug on chrome inspect tools. In this tools line 17 is my query. I update question.

Comment: Than put a break point in line 17 and check if your values are defined ;)